# google datastore - java - delete a property from all entities

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-datastore

Is there a way to delete a property from all entities in Google Datastore using Java? I want it to no longer be visible in the Google Cloud Console.

I tried setting the property to `null` in all entities but that did not work. It still shows up in the GCC when looking at the list of entities. It's just every single entry is `null`.

How can I completely remove this property from my entity?

EDIT:
Here is what it looks like in GCC. I want to just remove this property completely:

[image]

Comment: Did the answer provided solve your question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's [not possible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8196935/mass-updates-in-google-app-engine-datastore) to bulk update entities with a single query or command.  You will have to [read each entity individually](https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/concepts/entities#retrieving_an_entity), remove the field you no longer want (in memory, after you have read the entity), then [update the entity](https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/concepts/entities#updating_an_entity) again with the new set of properties that does not include the one you want removed.

Comment: So how can I do that in Java? I tried to read each entity, set the property to `null` and then save those entities back to the datastore. But the property still exists and it's value is show as `null` in GCC. I can't do something like set it as `undefined` as one could in javascript for example. Is there a way for me to read and save the entity back to the datastore with that one property as something like not-set or undefined?

Comment: I added an edit to my question.

Comment: Don't use null.  Null is valid value, and you don't want to put a value there.  Put only the properties you want into a Map, and feed that into the new entity.  It's hard to see where you might need a course correct because you've shown no code.  The steps are 1) read the entity, 2) copy only the properties you want from that into a new entity, 2) write the new entity in place of the first. Or use an entity builder loaded up with copied properties and literally `remove()` the ones you want out of it.